# Desplegar página con CURL php

Tags: php, webservice, api, curl, payu

Me gustaría desplegar una página que es consumida por post, cuando la consumo por CURL con el siguiente código PHP:

```
$curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://secure.payco.co/splitpayments.php",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "p_cust_id_cliente=32978&p_key=50c4f3e57a484c4a4d076394c368136915e0c99c&p_id_invoice=1212&p_description=fqwfqw&p_amount=100000&p_amount_base=100000&p_tax=16&p_email=michael.salazar9607@hotmail.com&p_currency_code=COP&p_signature=439f5383be66effbb0b720e9aef2923d&p_test_request=TRUE&p_split_type=02&p_split_merchant_receiver=32978&p_split_primary_receiver=32978&p_split_primary_receiver_fee=20",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Postman-Token: a390641b-b2ab-d928-df92-5dfe0c18b685",
        "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
    ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
```

Me muestra la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En cambio, ejecuto por un cliente html con el siguiente código:**

```
<form
 id="frm_botonePayco"
 name="frm_botonePayco"
 method="post"
 action="https://secure.payco.co/splitpayments.php">
 <input name="p_cust_id_cliente" type="hidden" value="9695">
 <input name="p_key" type="hidden" value="a1c7200f0e2029d11b62bfd863422d5db10a8397">
 <input name="p_id_invoice" type="hidden" value="1466810637">
 <input name="p_description" type="hidden" value="Prueba Checkout">
 <input name="p_currency_code" type="hidden" value="COP">
 <input name="p_amount" id="p_amount" type="hidden" value="100000">
 <input name="p_tax" id="p_tax" type="hidden" value="0">
 <input name="p_amount_base" id="p_amount_base" type="hidden" value="0">
 <input name="p_test_request" type="hidden" value="TRUE">
 <input name="p_url_response" type="hidden" value="">
 <input name="p_signature" type="hidden" id="signature" value="884eace509a854a94710e9db62bfc259">
 <input name="p_split_type" type="hidden" value="02">
 <input name="p_split_merchant_receiver" type="hidden" value="9695">
 <input name="p_split_primary_receiver" type="hidden" value="9695">
 <input name="p_split_primary_receiver_fee" type="hidden" value="5">
 <input name="p_split_receivers[0][id]" type="hidden" value="9695">
 <input name="p_split_receivers[0][fee]" type="hidden" value="2">
 <input name="p_signature_split" type="hidden" value="c0a4268c7bc06067d9d55bc5dc4f2aff">
 <input type="image" id="imagen" src="https://369969691f476073508a-60bf0867add971908d4f26a64519c2aa.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/btns/btn1.png">
```

Ejecuta perfectamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero realizar es que, se muestre como si ejecutara por el cliente HTML. ¿Hay alguna forma de que pueda hacer eso mismo desde PHP?

Muchas gracias y agradezco su atención.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No creo que sea posible,cuando tienes el checkout, este envía los datos por post y te redirecciona a la pasarela de pagos.

Adicionalmente puedes hacerlo aún más simple con el ONEPAGE CHECKOUT

```
<form>
        <script
            src="https://checkout.epayco.co/checkout.js"
            class="epayco-button"
            data-epayco-key="491d6a0b6e992cf924edd8d3d088aff1"
            data-epayco-amount="50000"
            data-epayco-name="Vestido Mujer Primavera"
            data-epayco-description="Vestido Mujer Primavera"
            data-epayco-currency="cop"
            data-epayco-country="co"
            data-epayco-test="true"
            data-epayco-external="false"
            data-epayco-response="https://ejemplo.com/respuesta.html"
            data-epayco-confirmation="https://ejemplo.com/confirmacion">
        </script>
    </form>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, como alternativa tuve que realizar esto.